Identify TV series with supernatural elements
I was stuck and standing on a very crowded train when I observed a seated passenger watching what I presume was a TV series on an iPad. It seemed intriguing, so i'd like to work out what it was.
The key elements (visuals only as the passenger was wearing headphones):

There was an visually striking, attractive, female red-head antagonist who seemed to have some supernatural powers (at one point when she seems to be threatening another character and the other character is only saved because she is tazed and stunned before she can complete whatever supernatural violence she was initiating)
Several characters seemed to have the ability to transport themselves over distance sometimes this seemed to involve drawing what looked like supernatural symbols on walls which would glow red
the red-headed female antagonist had telekinetic powers
she was also able to extract what looked like memories from other characters and this was illustrated by a dark smoke-like substance passing from them to her
Among the other characters there seemed to be a group of men, possible some fleeing from the female
Some other characters appeared to be able to perform spells usually indicated by, for example, blowing a powder into another character's face
the setting was relatively modern USA, possibly some in a small town (I think I saw a caption for "Normal, Illinois")


Could it be Abaddon from Supernatural?

@JudgeDredd Hard to tell from IMDB. Any pictures or screenshots of her in character: I think I would recognise a picture from the episode I saw.

Um, was the red-headed female the antagonist or protagonist? You appear to have referred to her as both.

This has more pictures of her http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Abaddon

@TrishLing sorry, typo. The redhead is definitely the antagonist in the episode I saw. Now corrected.

@JudgeDredd Ah, that could be it. I'll see if I can find the episodes on Amazon or Netflix and check.

Supernatural is available to stream on netflix.

You got all of that by observing a seated passenger on a crowded train? Some good eyesight you have there.

@Namechangedtomaskidentity I did, but I didn't get everything right as I found when I searched the episode and watched it. Abaddon is stabbed by a demon-killing knife not a taser, for example!

@JudgeDredd Unfortunately it isn't on Netflix in the UK, but I did find it on Amazon and you were quite right. I originally assumed it wasn't Supernatural as Abaddon only appears in redhead guise in series 8 (I think) and IMDB descriptions of early episodes don't look right. But thanks for the very fast recognition of the answer. For the record the episode is series 8 episode 12 "as time goes by"

I am glad to have helped. Supernatural is still available to stream instantly here on US in netflix. :P

The one you're referring to is Abaddon who is one of the villains in Season 8 & 9 of the TV series Supernatural which follows the tale of 2 brothers Sam and Dean Winchester who hunts demons and ghosts across the country.
Abaddon has the power of telekinesis, super strength and she has the power to read people's minds like how you've mentioned your question.

@matt_black The episode you watched is probably "As Time Goes By", which of course involves Abaddon and starts, at least, in Normal, Illinois. Here's a pic of the glowy symbol portal and Abbadon's extraction thingy

You are quite right. I was able to find the show online and watch exactly that episode. thanks to @judgedredd's link in the comments.
